# osTicket not able to access folder in Mailbox

Tags: php, pop3, mail-server, ticket-system, horde

I am using [osTicket](http://osticket.com) as ticket system on my site. Hope someone here will be able to help me out.
I was setting up an email in osTicket so that emails can be retrieved automatically. Fetching works properly but I am facing these issues:

1. Mail fetching:

   a. Sometimes the fetching works and I can see the new ticket.

   b. sometimes the email is deleted from mail box (as I have selected
      "Delete fetched emails") but no ticket is created.

   c. Sometimes the ticket is created and I can see it in database but
   it is not automatically assigned to anyone although a user is
   selected for Auto-assign in HelpTopics.
2. I cannot setup "Move to" for fetched emails in Mail Account page. When I enter the folder name and click on save, it gives error "Invalid or unknown archive folder!" and " Invalid or unknown mail folder! >> Mailbox is empty" errors. I created the folder from Horde but for some reason osTicket is not able to access that folder i guess. This is when Protocol is POP.
3. If I select IMAP and click on save, I get:
   Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {localhost:110/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX in /home/admin/lifeemail.com/support/include/class.mailfetch.php on line 130 on top of the page and below in the settings table i get this in red: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)

Point 2 is the main problem that is a headache. I tried getting help from Google and osTicket forum(its not very active) but I got nothing.

I am using 1.7 RC3.

Comment: I had the same problem, for the 3. IMAP port number was incorrect (993 on Hostgator if connection is SSL)

Answer (score 2):

try to type the folder name this way:

INBOX.myfolder

should work!

Answer (score 0):

Solved #2 for you, "When I enter the folder name and click on save, it gives error 'Invalid or unknown archive folder!' and 'Invalid or unknown mail folder! >> Mailbox is empty' errors."

I also could not enter the folder name into the "Move to folder" field. I solved it by clicking in the field, and keeping the mouse key held down while typing the name of the folder.